# How to make certain hosts bypass Fiddler?

Tags: fiddler

I have the Fiddler filters setup to "hide" the host "roaming.officeapps.live.com" and it does not show while I am debugging.

But the Fiddler proxy is still causing security issues (incorrect ssl certificate) to office, message relates to that host.

How can get a specific host to bypass Fiddler?

Or is the nature of a proxy based system that all requests go through it regardless?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`Tools` > `Fiddler Options` > `Connections` > `Bypass Fiddler for hosts that start with` or use the `HTTPS` tab to `Skip decryption for`.

Comment: Thanks @EricLaw. Its always in the last place you look.

Comment: You Helped me a lot.